# Rails: Want to show content from one table that is linked to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables: Locations and Departments. One Location can have many Departments. Is there a way to show all Departments regardless of what Location they're linked to?

For example: 1 Website Street has 2 departments, and 123 Cloud 9 Ave has 4 department. How can I show all 6 departments on a html.erb regardless of their location?

A department URL would look like `{server-port}/locations/1/departments/2`.

I've tried linking `@departments = Departments.all`, but it's looking for a Location.

I've also tried doing a loop for `@department = Department.find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your model called `Department` or `Departments`?

Assuming it's the former, you can do:

```
@departments = Department.all
```

(notice Department singular), this will assign @departments to every Department in your DB

Comment: That works, but how can I show the Location in the Department.all? 

I have `@locations = Location.all` in the controller, and then in the loop on the html.erb file, I have `@location = Location.find(params[:location_id])` but it can't find it.

Comment: I got it, it's `department.location`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `department` without setting the location ID because it's a nested resource.

If you want an URL like `/departments` to list all your departments then define a new resource outside location in `routes.rb`, or a path that points to a method in department controller.